# How to arrange table data into a

Tags: html, css

[Table with 3 rows. the first row span 1.5 column each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w14GB.jpg)

I am 2 months into learning html and i came across a task where i have no idea of where to start from. I want to implement a html table with 3 rows, the first row however should have two equal parts of columns and the other two to have 3 equal parts. Please help.

Here is a rough code for it:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>two</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>three</td>
      <td>four</td>
      <td> five</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>six</td>
      <td>seven</td>
      <td> eight</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use `colspan` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

Comment: please check this image  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w14GB.jpg )     this is what i want and colspan wont do this. atleast as per my trials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`colspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp). The colspan attribute defines the number of columns a table cell should span.

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='3'>one </td>
    <td colspan='3'> two </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>three</td>
    <td colspan='2'>four</td>
    <td colspan='2'> five</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>six</td>
    <td colspan='2'>seven</td>
    <td colspan='2'> eight</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: It would have been so cool if it just accepted colspan 1.5 :) or colspan 50% instead of having to add colspan 2 to the other columns!

Comment: ialso wished about colspan 1.5. Thanks alot though @HassanImam .